# Does pcolormesh plot the 2D array rightside-up or upside-down?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

Every time I go to plot a 2D array in `matplotlib` using, for example, `pcolormesh`, I have the same question: Is the resultant image showing the array rightside-up or upside-down?  That is, is index `(0, 0)` at the top left of the plot or the bottom left?

It's tedious to write a test every six months to remind myself.  This should be clearly documented in an obvious place, like SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is plotted upside-down, meaning the index `(0, 0)` is at the bottom left.